# How DD4T application gets the content data from the broker database? odata service or broker api?

Tags: dd4t

How DD4T application gets the content data from the broker database? odata service or broker api ?

Comment: which version of DD4T are you asking about, or just in general?

Comment: just in general.  I'm using DD4T 1.1 though

Comment: It comes from the database, though some people have created OData providers. Not sure for 1.1, but definitely for 1.31

Comment: At the time of writing, all versions of DD4T, for both Java and .Net use the standard Broker APIs to fetch data from the Broker database.

Comment: Check the video from the TDS talk about OData and DD4T here, http://2015.tridiondevelopersummit.com/2015/home/moving-a-customer-to-dd4t-with-azure-with-odata-and-elastic-search/

Comment: I have configured DD4T 2.0, Can it work with File System deployer instead of broker db

Answer (score 3):

DD4T (both Java and .Net) uses the standard Broker APIs to fetch data from the Broker database and thus requires all the content to be published to the database.

It is not possible to use a file system deployer, since the web application is setup to fetch all content from the Broker database.

There was an OData Page provider created for DD4T once, but when SDL Web 8 introduced microservices, the benefit of that OData provider fell away.